# Is there a way around this terraform cycle error?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to dynamically create a set of AWS API Gateway (v1) resources in Terraform based on a list of paths.

```
locals {
  http_endpoints = [
    "/api"
    "/api/something"
    "/api/something/else"
  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "http_function" {
  for_each     = {for path in local.http_endpoints : path => {
      path_part   = compact(split("/", path))[length(compact(split("/", path)))-1]
      parent_path = "/${join("/", slice(compact(split("/", path)), 0, length(compact(split("/", path))) -1))}"
    }
  }

  rest_api_id  = module.gateway.api_gateway_id
  parent_id    = each.value.parent_path == "/" ? module.gateway.api_gateway_root_id : aws_api_gateway_resource.http_function[each.value.parent_path].id
  path_part    = each.value.parts[length(each.value.parts) - 1]
}
```

The for_each expression results in a map like so:

```
{
  "/api" = { path_part = "api", parent_path = "/" }
  "/api/something" = { path_part = "something", parent_path = "/api" }
  "/api/something/else" = { path_part = "else", parent_path = "/api/something" }
}
```

I am hoping that terraform will see the dependencies between the resources instances and create them in order, so that each resource can be linked to the correct parent:

1. `aws_api_gateway_resource.http_function["/api"]`
2. `aws_api_gateway_resource.http_function["/api/something"]`
3. `aws_api_gateway_resource.http_function["/api/something/else"]`

But I am getting a cycle error listing all of the aws_api_gateway_resource instances.

```
Error: Cycle: aws_api_gateway_resource.http_function["/api/something/else"], 
aws_api_gateway_resource.http_function["/api/something"], 
aws_api_gateway_resource.http_function["/api"]
```

Is there a simple fix to make this work?
I know that I can use the OpenAPI method of constructing an API Gateway, but would like to avoid that.

Comment: "getting a cycle error" - what is the error **exactly**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible for one instance of a resource to refer to another instance of the same resource, because Terraform must resolve the dependency graph *before* it can evaluate `for_each`: the `for_each` expression has dependencies of its own that need to be taken into account.

For Amazon API Gateway in particular, a typical answer is to use the `body` argument to `aws_api_gateway_rest_api` which allows you to specify the entire API declaratively using a single OpenAPI schema document, which then avoids the need to refer to any specific API gateway resource IDs because the API gateway API automatically creates the necessary resource heirarchies to represent the paths you describe in your schema.

That approach is also a better fit for your `local.http_endpoints` data structure, because OpenAPI expects paths given as strings like you have in that list rather than requiring each path segment to be declared separately as nested objects.